# Class not found Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Boa tarde, estou começando com os estudos em laravel, no momento em que entrei no Eloquent ORM comecei a ter problemas.
Essa é a minha controller

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use estoque\Produto;
use Request;
class ProdutoController extends Controller {

public function lista(){
  $produtos = Produto::all();
  return view('produto.listagem')->with('produtos', $produtos);
}

Classe produto 

<?php namespace estoque;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Produto extends Model {
      protected $table = 'produtos';
  //
}
```

quando acesso a url para realizar a listagem apresenta o seguinte erro

> FatalErrorException in
>   /Users/kleitonbatista/Documents/Projetos/estoque/app/Http/Controllers/ProdutoController.php
>   line 10: Class 'estoque\Produto' not found
>   1.in ProdutoController.php line 10

Alguém poderia me dar uma luz de como resolver isso?
Estrutura do projeto
[image: Estrutura do projeto]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Olá! O problema está no namespace do arquivo produto.php e no "use estoque\Produto;" do controller.

Vejo 2 soluções para seu código compilar sem erros, são elas:

1. Usar a estrutura de arquivos padrão do laravel
2. Criar um namespace para alocar seu arquivo "Produto.php" (o que eu acho que foi o que você tentou fazer)

**Solução 1** (Usar estrutura padrão do laravel)

Nessa solução laravel cria os models na raíz da pasta "app" então para que o autoload funcione corretamente você precisa setar o namespace desses arquivos de modo que reflita essa estrutura.

Abra arquivo Produto.php e altere

DE:

> use estoque\Produto;

PARA:

> App\Produto;

Após isso abra o arquivo App/Http/Controllers/ProdutoController.php e altere

DE:

> use estoque\Produto;

PARA:

> use App\Produto;

O código final deverá ser:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Produto;
use Request;

class ProdutoController extends Controller {

    public function lista(){
        $produtos = Produto::all();
        return view('produto.listagem')->with('produtos', $produtos);
    }
}
```

e

```
<?php 
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Produto extends Model {
      protected $table = 'produtos';
  //
}
```

**Solução 2** (Criar um namespace "Estoque")

A dica é a mesma da solução anterior, seu namespace(nesse caso) tem que refletir a estrutura de pastas.

Se você deseja criar um namespace chamado "Estoque", sugiro criar uma pasta dentro da pasta "App" com no nome de "Estoque", Em seguida mova o arquivo "Produto.php" para dentro da pasta recém criada e edite o namespace do mesmo para "App\Estoque" logo e seguida abra arquivo "ProdutoController" e edite a seção "use"

DE:

> use estoque\Produto;

Para:

> use App\Estoque\Produto;

A estrutura final ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Estoque\Produto;
use Request;

class ProdutoController extends Controller {

    public function lista(){
        $produtos = Produto::all();
        return view('produto.listagem')->with('produtos', $produtos);
    }
}
```

e

```
<?php 
namespace App\Estoque;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Produto extends Model {
      protected $table = 'produtos';
  //
}
```

A estrutura de pastas ficará semelhante a esta

```
+ estoque
   ...
   + app
     ... 
     + Http
     + Estoque
         - Produto.php
     ...
```