# A classe Defeito não existe?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Estou com seguinte erro:

> ReflectionException in Container.php line 731: Class App\Defeito does not exist

estou utilizando laravel 5.4, ja verifiquei aparentemente esta tudo certo.

Codigo: `Defeito.php`

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Defeito extends Model {

   protected $table = 'defeito';
   public $timestamps = false;

}
```

Código: `Controller`:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use League\Flysystem\Exception;

class DefeitoController extends Controller 
{

    private $defeitos;

    public function __construct(Defei $defeitos) 
    {
        $this -> defeitos = $defeitos;
    }

    public function salvar(Request $request) {

      try {

        $defeito = new $this -> defeitos;
        $defeito -> assunto      =   $request -> input('assunto');
        $defeito -> duvida       =   $request -> input('duvida');
        $defeito -> satisfacao   =   $request -> input('satisfacao');
        $defeito -> contato      =   $request -> input('contato');

        $defeito->save();
        return response()->json(['status' => 1, 
                                'msg' => 'Defeito salvo com sucesso']);

      } catch (Exception $e ) {
        return response()->json(['status' => 0, 
                                 'msg' => 'Houve um erro ao salvar o defeito']);
      }
   }

}
```

Rota: `API`

```
Route::post('clientes/salvar', 'ClienteController@salvar');
```

Rota: `Web`

```
Route::get('/defeito', function () {
    return view('template/form-defeitos');
});
```

Comment: Não seria `App\Models\Defeito`?

Comment: não dar erro: undefined namespace Model.

Comment: Mesmo com `Models`, no plural?

Comment: isso mesmo .....

Comment: estava tudo certo, porém agora começou dar esse erro.

Comment: Então edite sua pergunta e insira os códigos. Se antes funcionava, coloque também o que você alterou no projeto.

Comment: in RouteCollection.php line 161
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 533, eu so coloquei alguns forms.

Comment: Todos os lugares que vi, os models no framework Laravel estão no namespace `Models`, então você deve ter feito algo de errado. Edite a pergunta e coloque os códigos.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Class not found Laravel](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/189519/class-not-found-laravel)

Comment: O namespace o model deve ser namespace `App\Models;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Importe a classe Defeito no Controler com o operador use

```
use App\Defeito;
```

No construtor corrija o nome de:

```
public function __construct(Defei $defeitos) {
      $this -> defeitos = $defeitos;
}
```

para:

```
public function __construct(Defeito $defeito) {
      $this -> defeito = $defeito;
}
```

Se esta usando DI no construtor, não tem a necessidade de novamente estender a classe "new" dentro do método salvar, já que ele foi declarada no objeto $this->defeito.

Corrigida ficaria assim.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Defeito; //Verifique se é este o namespace correto

class DefeitoController extends Controller {

    private $defeito;

    public function __construct(Defeito $defeito) {
        $this -> defeito = $defeito;
    }

    public function salvar(Request $request) {

        try {

            $defeito -> assunto      =   $request -> input('assunto');
            $defeito -> duvida       =   $request -> input('duvida');
            $defeito -> satisfacao   =   $request -> input('satisfacao');
            $defeito -> contato      =   $request -> input('contato');

            $defeito->save();
            return response()->json(['status' => 1, 'msg' => 'Defeito salvo com sucesso']);

        } catch (\Exception $e ) {
            return response()->json(['status' => 0, 'msg' => 'Houve um erro ao salvar o defeito']);
        }
    }

}
```